# NPM vs. Bower vs. Browserify vs. Gulp vs. Grunt vs. Webpack

Tags: gruntjs, npm, gulp, bower, webpack

I'm trying to summarize my knowledge about the most popular JavaScript package managers, bundlers, and task runners. Please correct me if I'm wrong:

- `npm` & `bower` are package managers. They just download the dependencies and don't know how to build projects on their own. What they know is to call `webpack`/`gulp`/`grunt` after fetching all the dependencies.
- `bower` is like `npm`, but builds a flattened dependency trees (unlike `npm` which does it recursively). Meaning `npm` fetches the dependencies for each dependency (may fetch the same a few times), while `bower` expects you to manually include sub-dependencies. Sometimes `bower` and `npm` are used together for front-end and back-end respectively (since each megabyte might matter in front-end).
- `grunt` and `gulp` are task runners to automate everything that can be automated (i.e. compile CSS/Sass, optimize images, make a bundle and minify/transpile it).
- `grunt` vs. `gulp` (is like `maven` vs. `gradle` or configuration vs. code). Grunt is based on configuring separate independent tasks, each task opens/handles/closes file. Gulp requires less amount of code and is based on Node streams, which allows it to build pipe chains (without reopening the same file) and makes it faster.
- `webpack` (`webpack-dev-server`) - for me it's a task runner with hot reloading of changes which allows you to forget about all JS/CSS watchers.
- `npm`/`bower` + plugins may replace task runners. Their abilities often intersect so there are different implications if you need to use `gulp`/`grunt` over `npm` + plugins. But task runners are definitely better for complex tasks (e.g. "on each build create bundle, transpile from ES6 to ES5, run it at all browsers emulators, make screenshots and deploy to dropbox through ftp").
- `browserify` allows packaging node modules for browsers. `browserify` vs `node`'s `require` is actually [AMD vs CommonJS](https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/).

***Questions:***

1. *What is `webpack` & `webpack-dev-server`?* Official documentation says it's a module bundler but for me it's just a task runner. *What's the difference?*
2. *Where would you use `browserify`? Can't we do the same with node/ES6 imports?*
3. *When would you use `gulp`/`grunt` over `npm` + plugins?*
4. *Please provide examples when you need to use a combination*

Comment: time to add in [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/)? 

Comment: this is a very reasonable question. pseudo web-devs like me stumble over all the packages that are implemented in a weekly fashion..

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f

Comment: @Fisherman I'm totally new to this, and it seems completely nuts...

Comment: @DavidStosik may be you missed the encouraging parts in comments sections :)

Comment: @Fisherman The "recommended" comment I just read was even worse! D:
I just want to build a fricking static page that uses a couple of CSS/JS libs, and would benefit from having a tool that can compile that together... Throw in some templating engine to give some rest to my Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V fingers, and that'd be perfect... And yet, hours into it, still trying to find a way to go...

Comment: @DavidStosik : its a one time investment. after setting up perfectly you are ready to fly

Comment: @gman, [jspm](http://jspm.io/) which uses rollup too.

Comment: I've been a web developer for 16+ years and much of that was under the Microsoft .NET umbrella where they sheltered us for many years from tools like these before unleashing hell upon us by suddenly "being cool" with all of it at once (even if their IDE couldn't handle it [I hear vs2017 is better, but I'll stick with WebStorm now {Digresption}]). Anywho, these things complicate the development infrastructure and require much more initial setup time to get it just right, but once it's in place and working, man it's sweet!

Comment: Time to add Yarn (http://yarnpkg.com) ?

Comment: @Fisherman seems somewhat naive to imagine it'll really be a 'one time investment'... after a few years working with tech, the motivation to learn these layers of extraneous complication is, for me, greatly diminished by bitter experience of things that seemed to be working well being made obsolete. Trendy web tech like this has a bad smell from that POV (and I'm not even old).

Comment: I think you should also add the Babel in the list.

Comment: Npm knows nothing about webpack/gulp/grunt at all. It just knows how to install your dependencies, run your application and your tests. You might add some extra functionality by adding custom scripts, though.

Comment: Welcome to the rabbit hole.

Comment: This is the poster child question for "needs more focus"   There are 6 questions directly asked and about 10 more indirectly asked as "is this correct?"

Answer (score 1108, accepted):

#### Webpack and Browserify

Webpack and Browserify do pretty much the same job, which is **processing your code to be used in a target environment** (mainly browser, though you can target other environments like Node). Result of such processing is one or more **bundles** - assembled scripts suitable for targeted environment.

For example, let's say you wrote ES6 code divided into modules and want to be able to run it in a browser. If those modules are Node modules, the browser won't understand them since they exist only in the Node environment. ES6 modules also won't work in older browsers like IE11. Moreover, you might have used experimental language features (ES next proposals) that browsers don't implement yet so running such script would just throw errors. Tools like Webpack and Browserify solve these problems by **translating such code to a form a browser is able to execute**. On top of that, they make it possible to apply a huge variety of optimisations on those bundles.

However, Webpack and Browserify differ in many ways, Webpack offers many tools by default (e.g. code splitting), while Browserify can do this only after downloading plugins but **using both leads to very similar results**. It comes down to personal preference (Webpack is trendier). Btw, Webpack is not a task runner, it is just processor of your files (it processes them by so called loaders and plugins) and it can be run (among other ways) by a task runner.

---

#### Webpack Dev Server

Webpack Dev Server provides a similar solution to Browsersync - a development server where you can deploy your app rapidly as you are working on it, and verify your development progress immediately, with the dev server automatically refreshing the browser on code changes or even propagating changed code to browser without reloading with so called hot module replacement.

---

#### Task runners vs NPM scripts

I've been using Gulp for its conciseness and easy task writing, but have later found out I need neither Gulp nor Grunt at all. Everything I have ever needed could have been done using NPM scripts to run 3rd-party tools through their API. **Choosing between Gulp, Grunt or NPM scripts depends on taste and experience of your team.**

While tasks in Gulp or Grunt are easy to read even for people not so familiar with JS, it is yet another tool to require and learn and I personally prefer to narrow my dependencies and make things simple. On the other hand, replacing these tasks with the combination of NPM scripts and (propably JS) scripts which run those 3rd party tools (eg. Node script configuring and running [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) for cleaning purposes) might be more challenging. But in the majority of cases, **those three are equal in terms of their results.**

---

#### Examples

As for the examples, I suggest you have a look at this [React starter project](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit), which shows you a nice combination of NPM and JS scripts covering the whole build and deploy process. You can find those NPM scripts in `package.json` in the root folder, in a property named `scripts`. There you will mostly encounter commands like `babel-node tools/run start`. Babel-node is a CLI tool (not meant for production use), which at first compiles ES6 file `tools/run` (run.js file located in [tools](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/tree/master/tools)) - basically a runner utility. This runner takes a function as an argument and executes it, which in this case is `start` - another utility (`start.js`) responsible for bundling source files (both client and server) and starting the application and development server (the dev server will be probably either Webpack Dev Server or Browsersync).

Speaking more precisely, `start.js` creates both client and server side bundles, starts an express server and after a successful launch initializes Browser-sync, which at the time of writing looked like this (please refer to [react starter project](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) for the newest code).

```
const bs = Browsersync.create();  
bs.init({
      ...(DEBUG ? {} : { notify: false, ui: false }),

      proxy: {
        target: host,
        middleware: [wpMiddleware, ...hotMiddlewares],
      },

      // no need to watch '*.js' here, webpack will take care of it for us,
      // including full page reloads if HMR won't work
      files: ['build/content/**/*.*'],
}, resolve)
```

The important part is `proxy.target`, where they set server address they want to proxy, which could be http://localhost:3000, and Browsersync starts a server listening on http://localhost:3001, where the generated assets are served with automatic change detection and hot module replacement. As you can see, there is another configuration property `files` with individual files or patterns Browser-sync watches for changes and reloads the browser if some occur, but as the comment says, Webpack takes care of watching js sources by itself with HMR, so they cooperate there.

Now I don't have any equivalent example of such Grunt or Gulp configuration, but with Gulp (and somewhat similarly with Grunt) you would write individual tasks in gulpfile.js like

```
gulp.task('bundle', function() {
  // bundling source files with some gulp plugins like gulp-webpack maybe
});

gulp.task('start', function() {
  // starting server and stuff
});
```

where you would be doing essentially pretty much the same things as in the starter-kit, this time with task runner, which solves some problems for you, but presents its own issues and some difficulties during learning the usage, and as I say, the more dependencies you have, the more can go wrong. And that is the reason I like to get rid of such tools.

Comment: great answer! May you describe pls in which way webpack/browserify manage reuse node modules at browser please?

Comment: Webpack assembles dependencies (exported module values) into object (installedModules). Each module is therefore property of that object and name of such property represents its id (eg. 1, 2, 3 ... etc.). Everytime you require such module in your source, webpack transforms the value into function call with module id in argument (eg. __webpack_require__(1)), which returns the right dependency based on search in installedModules by module id. I'm not sure, how Browserify handles it.

Comment: @Dan Skočdopole Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Which matter do you want me to elaborate on ?

Comment: Can you please add examples? Like shortest code to use `webpack-dev-server` and `Browsersync` to run a server, example tasks in grunt and gulp etc. And moving react starter project examples to the answer itself will be also helpful, since repo may change the code in future. (Or link to the exact snapshot of the repo)

Comment: I don´t agree with presenting basic usage of gulp or grunt, these two are easy to compare using google, webpack-dev-server requires to understand webpack first, and that is out of scope of this question / answer, but I have presented some Browsersync config. You are right with the starter-kit, and I elaborated on it more.

Comment: +1 for reducing dependencies to keep things simple rather than following the (more) popular opinion that every new package must be used!

Comment: Very good.but I have a question,what is the relation between node_module and webpack?ِDoes webpack have loaders itself?Or we should download loaders and then wepback uses them?

Comment: @AliAbbaszade node_modules is a folder where npm or yarn installs dependencies. Webpack is such a dependency and so are loaders used by webpack. Not sure if webpack has any default loaders, but it has plugins in the webpack package that you can use. So yes, you have to download loaders separately and declare them in webpack's config so that you can use them.

Comment: Hii bro I see you have outstanding knowledge of webpack can you please help me on my thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030506/how-to-update-multiple-bundled-js-files-using-webpack/60090572#60090572

Answer (score 735):

***Update October 2018***

If you are still uncertain about Front-end dev, you can take a quick look into an excellent resource here.

https://github.com/kamranahmedse/developer-roadmap

***Update June 2018***

Learning modern JavaScript is tough if you haven’t been there since the beginning. If you are the newcomer, remember to check this excellent written to have a better overview.

https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/modern-javascript-explained-for-dinosaurs-f695e9747b70

***Update July 2017***

Recently I found a comprehensive guide from Grab team about how to approach front-end development in 2017. You can check it out as below.

https://github.com/grab/front-end-guide

---

I've been also searching for this quite some time since there are a lot of tools out there and each of them benefits us in a different aspect. The community is divided across tools like `Browserify, Webpack, jspm, Grunt and Gulp`. You might also hear about `Yeoman or Slush`. That’s not a problem, it’s just confusing for everyone trying to understand a clear path forward.

Anyway, I would like to contribute something.

### Table Of Contents

- Table Of Content
- 1. Package Manager

  - NPM
  - Bower
  - Difference between `Bower` and `NPM`
  - Yarn
  - jspm
- 2. Module Loader/Bundling

  - RequireJS
  - Browserify
  - Webpack
  - SystemJS
- 3. Task runner

  - Grunt
  - Gulp
- 4. Scaffolding tools

  - Slush and Yeoman

---

### 1. Package Manager

Package managers simplify installing and updating project dependencies, which are libraries such as: `jQuery, Bootstrap`, etc - everything that is used on your site and isn't written by you.

Browsing all the library websites, downloading and unpacking the archives, copying files into the projects — all of this is replaced with a few commands in the terminal.

#### [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/)

It stands for: `Node JS package manager` helps you to manage all the libraries your software relies on. You would define your needs in a file called `package.json` and run `npm install` in the command line... then BANG, your packages are downloaded and ready to use. It could be used both for `front-end` and `back-end` libraries.

#### [Bower](https://bower.io/)

For front-end package management, the concept is the same with NPM. All your libraries are stored in a file named `bower.json` and then run `bower install` in the command line.

> Bower is recommended their user to [migrate over to npm or yarn](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/). Please be careful

#### Difference between `Bower` and `NPM`

> The biggest difference between `Bower` and `NPM` is that NPM does nested
> dependency tree while Bower requires a flat dependency tree as below.
>
> Quoting from [What is the difference between Bower and npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641899/what-is-the-difference-between-bower-and-npm)

**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/)**

```
project root
[node_modules] // default directory for dependencies
 -> dependency A
 -> dependency B
    [node_modules]
    -> dependency A

 -> dependency C
    [node_modules]
    -> dependency B
      [node_modules]
       -> dependency A
    -> dependency D
```

**[Bower](https://bower.io/)**

```
project root
[bower_components] // default directory for dependencies
 -> dependency A
 -> dependency B // needs A
 -> dependency C // needs B and D
 -> dependency D
```

> There are some updates on [`npm 3 Duplication and Deduplication`](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3-dupe),
> please open the doc for more detail.

#### [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/)

A new package manager for `JavaScript` [published](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1840075619545360) by `Facebook` recently with some more advantages compared to `NPM`. And with Yarn, you still can use both [`NPM`](https://www.npmjs.com/)and [`Bower`](https://bower.io/) registry to fetch the package. If you've installed a package before, `yarn` creates a cached copy which facilitates `offline package installs`.

#### [jspm](http://jspm.io/)

JSPM is a package manager for the `SystemJS` universal module loader, built on top of the dynamic `ES6` module loader. It is not an entirely new package manager with its own set of rules, rather it works on top of existing package sources. Out of the box, it works with `GitHub` and `npm`. As most of the `Bower` based packages are based on `GitHub`, we can install those packages using `jspm` as well. It has a registry that lists most of the commonly used front-end packages for easier installation.

> See the different between [`Bower`](https://bower.io/) and `jspm`:
> [Package Manager: Bower vs jspm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416813/package-manager-bower-vs-jspm)

---

### 2. Module Loader/Bundling

Most projects of any scale will have their code split between several files. You can just include each file with an individual `<script>` tag, however, `<script>` establishes a new HTTP connection, and for small files – which is a goal of modularity – the time to set up the connection can take significantly longer than transferring the data. While the scripts are downloading, no content can be changed on the page.

- The problem of download time can largely be solved by concatenating a group of simple modules into a single file and minifying it.

E.g

```html
<head>
    <title>Wagon</title>
    <script src=“build/wagon-bundle.js”></script>
</head>
```

- The performance comes at the expense of flexibility though. If your modules have inter-dependency, this lack of flexibility may be a showstopper.

E.g

```html
<head>
    <title>Skateboard</title>
    <script src=“connectors/axle.js”></script>
    <script src=“frames/board.js”></script>
    <!-- skateboard-wheel and ball-bearing both depend on abstract-rolling-thing -->
    <script src=“rolling-things/abstract-rolling-thing.js”></script>
    <script src=“rolling-things/wheels/skateboard-wheel.js”></script>
    <!-- but if skateboard-wheel also depends on ball-bearing -->
    <!-- then having this script tag here could cause a problem -->
    <script src=“rolling-things/ball-bearing.js”></script>
    <!-- connect wheels to axle and axle to frame -->
    <script src=“vehicles/skateboard/our-sk8bd-init.js”></script>
</head>
```

Computers can do that better than you can, and that is why you should use a tool to automatically bundle everything into a single file.

**Then we heard about `RequireJS`, `Browserify`, `Webpack` and `SystemJS`**

#### [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

It is a `JavaScript` file and module loader. It is optimized for in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments, like `Node`.

E.g: **myModule.js**

```js
// package/lib is a dependency we require
define(["package/lib"], function (lib) {
  // behavior for our module
  function foo() {
    lib.log("hello world!");
  }

  // export (expose) foo to other modules as foobar
  return {
    foobar: foo,
  };
});
```

In `main.js`, we can import `myModule.js` as a dependency and use it.

```
require(["package/myModule"], function(myModule) {
    myModule.foobar();
});
```

And then in our `HTML`, we can refer to use with `RequireJS`.

```
<script src=“app/require.js” data-main=“main.js” ></script>
```

> Read more about `CommonJS` and `AMD` to get understanding easily.
> [Relation between CommonJS, AMD and RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs)

#### [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Set out to allow the use of `CommonJS` formatted modules in the browser. Consequently, `Browserify` isn’t as much a module loader as a module bundler: `Browserify` is entirely a build-time tool, producing a bundle of code that can then be loaded client-side.

Start with a build machine that has node & npm installed, and get the package:

```
npm install -g –save-dev browserify
```

Write your modules in `CommonJS` format

```js
//entry-point.js
var foo = require("../foo.js");
console.log(foo(4));
```

And when happy, issue the command to bundle:

```
browserify entry-point.js -o bundle-name.js
```

Browserify recursively finds all dependencies of entry-point and assembles them into a single file:

```html
<script src="”bundle-name.js”"></script>
```

#### [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)

It bundles all of your static assets, including `JavaScript`, images, CSS, and more, into a single file. It also enables you to process the files through different types of loaders. You could write your `JavaScript` with `CommonJS` or `AMD` modules syntax. It attacks the build problem in a fundamentally more integrated and opinionated manner. In `Browserify` you use `Gulp/Grunt` and a long list of transforms and plugins to get the job done. `Webpack` offers enough power out of the box that you typically don’t need `Grunt` or `Gulp` at all.

Basic usage is beyond simple. Install Webpack like Browserify:

```
npm install -g –save-dev webpack
```

And pass the command an entry point and an output file:

```
webpack ./entry-point.js bundle-name.js
```

#### [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)

It is a module loader that **can import modules at run time in any of the popular formats** used today (`CommonJS, UMD, AMD, ES6`). It is built on top of the `ES6` module loader polyfill and is smart enough to detect the format being used and handle it appropriately. `SystemJS` can also transpile ES6 code (with `Babel` or `Traceur`) or other languages such as `TypeScript` and `CoffeeScript` using plugins.

> Want to know what is the `node module` and why it is not well adapted to in-browser.

> More useful article:
>
> - https://medium.com/@housecor/browserify-vs-webpack-b3d7ca08a0a9#.c1q7ao3h4
> - http://jamesknelson.com/which-build-system-should-i-use-for-my-javascript-app/
> - https://appendto.com/2016/06/the-short-history-of-javascript-module-loaders/

---

> Why `jspm` and `SystemJS`?
>
> One of the main goals of `ES6` modularity is to make it really simple
> to install and use any Javascript library from anywhere on the
> Internet (`Github`, `npm`, etc.). Only two things are needed:
>
> - A single command to install the library
> - One single line of code to import the library and use it
>
> So with `jspm`, you can do it.
>
> 1. Install the library with a command: `jspm install jquery`
> 2. Import the library with a single line of code, no need to external reference inside your HTML file.
>
> **display.js**
>
> ```
> var $ = require('jquery');
>
> $('body').append("I've imported jQuery!");
> ```
>
> 3. Then you configure these things within `System.config({ ... })` before
>    importing your module. Normally when run `jspm init`, there will be a file
>    named `config.js` for this purpose.
> 4. To make these scripts run, we need to load `system.js` and `config.js` on the HTML page. After that, we will load the `display.js` file using
>    the `SystemJS` module loader.
>
> **index.html**
>
> ```
> <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
> <script src="config.js"></script>
> <script>
>   System.import("scripts/display.js");
> </script>
> ```
>
> Noted: You can also use `npm` with `Webpack` as Angular 2 has applied it. Since `jspm` was developed to integrate with `SystemJS` and it works on top of the existing `npm` source, so your answer is up to you.

---

### 3. Task runner

Task runners and build tools are primarily command-line tools. Why we need to use them: In one word: **automation**. The less work you have to do when performing repetitive tasks like **minification, compilation, unit testing, linting** which previously cost us a lot of times to do with command line or even manually.

#### [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)

You can create automation for your development environment to pre-process codes or create build scripts with a config file and it seems very difficult to handle a complex task. Popular in the last few years.

Every task in `Grunt` is an array of different plugin configurations, that simply get executed one after another, in a strictly independent, and sequential fashion.

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    clean: {
    src: ['build/app.js', 'build/vendor.js']
    },

    copy: {
    files: [{
        src: 'build/app.js',
        dest: 'build/dist/app.js'
    }]
    }

    concat: {
    'build/app.js': ['build/vendors.js', 'build/app.js']
    }

    // ... other task configurations ...

});

grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'bower', 'browserify', 'concat', 'copy']);
```

#### [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)

Automation just like `Grunt` but instead of configurations, you can write `JavaScript` with streams like it's a node application. Prefer these days.

This is a `Gulp` sample task declaration.

```js
//import the necessary gulp plugins
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var minifyCss = require("gulp-minify-css");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

//declare the task
gulp.task("sass", function (done) {
  gulp
    .src("./scss/ionic.app.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./www/css/"))
    .pipe(
      minifyCss({
        keepSpecialComments: 0,
      })
    )
    .pipe(rename({ extname: ".min.css" }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./www/css/"))
    .on("end", done);
});
```

> See more: https://preslav.me/2015/01/06/gulp-vs-grunt-why-one-why-the-other/

---

### 4. Scaffolding tools

#### Slush and Yeoman

You can create starter projects with them. For example, you are planning to build a prototype with HTML and SCSS, then instead of manually create some folder like scss, css, img, fonts. You can just install `yeoman` and run a simple script. Then everything here for you.

Find more [here](http://yeoman.io/).

```
npm install -g yo
npm install --global generator-h5bp
yo h5bp
```

> See more: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-NPM-Bower-Grunt-Gulp-Webpack-Browserify-Slush-Yeoman-and-Express

---

My answer is not matched with the content of the question but when I'm searching for this knowledge on Google, I always see the question on top so that I decided to answer it in summary.

Answer (score 68):

**OK,** they all have got some similarities, they do the same things for you in different and similar ways, I divide them in **3 main groups** as below:

---

**1) Module bundlers**

webpack and browserify as popular ones, work like task runners but with more flexibility, aslo it will bundle everything together as your setting, so you can point to the result as bundle.js for example in one single file including the CSS and Javascript, for more details of each, look at the details below:

**webpack**

> webpack is a module bundler for modern JavaScript applications. When
>   webpack processes your application, it recursively builds a dependency
>   graph that includes every module your application needs, then packages
>   all of those modules into a small number of bundles - often only one -
>   to be loaded by the browser.
>
> It is incredibly configurable, but to get started you only need to
>   understand Four Core Concepts: entry, output, loaders, and plugins.
>
> This document is intended to give a high-level overview of these
>   concepts, while providing links to detailed concept specific
>   use-cases.

more [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/)

**browserify**

> Browserify is a development tool that allows us to write node.js-style
>   modules that compile for use in the browser. Just like node, we write
>   our modules in separate files, exporting external methods and
>   properties using the module.exports and exports variables. We can even
>   require other modules using the require function, and if we omit the
>   relative path it’ll resolve to the module in the node_modules
>   directory.

more [here](http://blakeembrey.com/articles/2013/09/introduction-to-browserify/)

---

**2) Task runners**

gulp and grunt are task runners, basically what they do, creating tasks and run them whenever you want, for example you install a plugin to minify your CSS and then run it each time to do minifying, more details about each:

**gulp**

> gulp.js is an open-source JavaScript toolkit by Fractal Innovations
>   and the open source community at GitHub, used as a streaming build
>   system in front-end web development. It is a task runner built on
>   Node.js and Node Package Manager (npm), used for automation of
>   time-consuming and repetitive tasks involved in web development like
>   minification, concatenation, cache busting, unit testing, linting,
>   optimization etc. gulp uses a code-over-configuration approach to
>   define its tasks and relies on its small, single-purposed plugins to
>   carry them out. gulp ecosystem has 1000+ such plugins made available
>   to choose from.

more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulp.js)

**grunt**

> Grunt is a JavaScript task runner, a tool used to automatically
>   perform frequently used tasks such as minification, compilation, unit
>   testing, linting, etc. It uses a command-line interface to run custom
>   tasks defined in a file (known as a Gruntfile). Grunt was created by
>   Ben Alman and is written in Node.js. It is distributed via npm.
>   Presently, there are more than five thousand plugins available in the
>   Grunt ecosystem.

more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunt_(software))

---

**3) Package managers**

package managers, what they do is managing plugins you need in your application and install them for you through github etc using package.json, very handy to update you modules, install them and sharing your app across, more details for each:

**npm**

> npm is a package manager for the JavaScript programming language. It
>   is the default package manager for the JavaScript runtime environment
>   Node.js. It consists of a command line client, also called npm, and an
>   online database of public packages, called the npm registry. The
>   registry is accessed via the client, and the available packages can be
>   browsed and searched via the npm website.

more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/)

**bower**

> Bower can manage components that contain HTML, CSS, JavaScript, fonts
>   or even image files. Bower doesn’t concatenate or minify code or do
>   anything else - it just installs the right versions of the packages
>   you need and their dependencies.
>   To get started, Bower works by fetching and installing packages from
>   all over, taking care of hunting, finding, downloading, and saving the
>   stuff you’re looking for. Bower keeps track of these packages in a
>   manifest file, bower.json.

more [here](https://bower.io/)

and the most recent package manager that shouldn't be missed, it's young and fast in real work environment compare to npm which I was mostly using before, for reinstalling modules, it do double checks the node_modules folder to check the existence of the module, also seems installing the modules takes less time:

**yarn**

> Yarn is a package manager for your code. It allows you to use and
>   share code with other developers from around the world. Yarn does this
>   quickly, securely, and reliably so you don’t ever have to worry.
>
> Yarn allows you to use other developers’ solutions to different
>   problems, making it easier for you to develop your software. If you
>   have problems, you can report issues or contribute back, and when the
>   problem is fixed, you can use Yarn to keep it all up to date.
>
> Code is shared through something called a package (sometimes referred
>   to as a module). A package contains all the code being shared as well
>   as a package.json file which describes the package.

more [here](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/getting-started/)

---

Comment: Is there a list of gulp plugins ? are there really 1000+? npm only returns 20 or so?

Comment: Great summary. Should be an entry point for any discussion about a modern web development.

Comment: @flurbius Yes, here: https://gulpjs.com/plugins/. Currently there seems to be 3,465 Gulp plugins.

Comment: What about `Parcel`?

Answer (score 54):

You can find some technical comparison on [npmcompare](https://npmcompare.com)

[Comparing browserify vs. grunt vs. gulp vs. webpack](https://npmcompare.com/compare/browserify,grunt,gulp,webpack)

As you can see webpack is very well maintained with a new version coming out every 4 days on average.
But Gulp seems to have the biggest community of them all (with over 20K stars on Github)
Grunt seems a bit neglected (compared to the others)

So if need to choose one over the other i would go with Gulp

Comment: webpack is now 26k starts on Github and gulp with 25.7k. Can't use the popularity factor to decide anymore ...

Answer (score 17):

> What is webpack & webpack-dev-server? Official documentation says it's a module bundler but for me it's just a task runner. What's the difference?

[webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) is a live reloading web server that *Webpack* developers use to get immediate feedback what they do. It should only be used during development.

This project is heavily inspired by the [nof5](https://github.com/peerigon/nof5) unit test tool.

*Webpack* as the name implies will create a *SINGLE* **pack**age for the **web**. The package will be minimized, and combined into a single file (we still live in HTTP 1.1 age). *Webpack* does the magic of combining the resources (JavaScript, CSS, images) and injecting them like this: `<script src="assets/bundle.js"></script>`.

It can also be called *module bundler* because it must understand module dependencies, and how to grab the dependencies and to bundle them together.

> Where would you use browserify? Can't we do the same with node/ES6 imports?

You could use *Browserify* on the exact same tasks where you would use *Webpack*. – *Webpack* is more compact, though.

Note that the [ES6 module loader features](https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7) in *Webpack2* are using *System.import*, which not a single browser supports natively.

> When would you use gulp/grunt over npm + plugins?

You can [forget](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/) *Gulp, Grunt, Brokoli, Brunch and Bower*. Directly use npm command line scripts instead and you can eliminate extra packages like these here for *Gulp*:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
  minifyCSS     = require('gulp-minify-css'),
  sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
  browserify    = require('gulp-browserify'),
  uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
  rename        = require('gulp-rename'),
  jshint        = require('gulp-jshint'),
  jshintStyle   = require('jshint-stylish'),
  replace       = require('gulp-replace'),
  notify        = require('gulp-notify'),
```

You can probably use *Gulp* and *Grunt* config file generators when creating config files for your project. This way you don't need to install *Yeoman* or similar tools.

Answer (score 14):

`Webpack` is a bundler. Like `Browserfy` it looks in the codebase for module requests (`require` or `import`) and resolves them recursively. What is more, you can configure `Webpack` to resolve not just JavaScript-like modules, but CSS, images, HTML, literally everything. What especially makes me excited about `Webpack`, you can combine both compiled and dynamically loaded modules in the same app. Thus one get a real performance boost, especially over HTTP/1.x. How exactly you you do it I described with examples here http://dsheiko.com/weblog/state-of-javascript-modules-2017/
As an alternative for bundler one can think of `Rollup.js` (https://rollupjs.org/), which optimizes the code during compilation, but stripping all the found unused chunks.

For `AMD`, instead of `RequireJS` one can go with native `ES2016 module system`, but loaded with `System.js` (https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)

Besides, I would point that `npm` is often used as an automating tool like `grunt` or `gulp`. Check out https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts. I personally  go now with npm scripts only avoiding other automation tools, though in past I was very much into `grunt`. With other tools you have to rely on countless plugins for packages, that often are not good written and not being actively maintained. `npm` knows its packages, so you call to any of locally installed packages by name like:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm http-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Actually you as a rule do not need any plugin if the package supports CLI.

Answer (score 13):

Yarn is a recent package manager that probably deserves to be mentioned.
So, here it is: https://yarnpkg.com/

As far as I know it can fetch both npm and bower dependencies and has other appreciated features.