# Efficiently Bundling Dependencies with Electron App for Distribution

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, electron

I am trying to figure out an effective way to bundle and distribute various dependencies (node modules and/or "client"-side scripts and framework like Angular) with my Electron App.

Although the basic approach of `npm install module-name --save` works well for development, it is not so good in the end when it comes to minimizing the size of your app and using minified resources at runtime. For instance, virtually all npm packages (including node modules) come with a lot of "extra baggage" like readmes, various versions of components (minified, not minified, ES2015, no-ES2015, etc). While these are great for development, all these files have absolutely no need to be included in the version you will be distributing.

Currently there seem to be 2 ways to sort of address the problem:

- [Electron Builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) recommends using 2-file `package.json` system.
- Any dependency that is used during development only should be npm-installed using `--save-dev` and then prunning should be used when building the app for distribution.

In that regard I have several questions:

1. I am not quite sure why there is a need for 2-file `package.json` system if one can install dev-only modules/ dependencies with `--save-dev` and then use pruning during the actual app build/compilation?
2. Regardless of which method above is used, you still end up with full npm packages in your app, inclduying all the miscellaneous/duplicated files that are not used by your app. So how does one "prune" so to speak the npm packages themselves so that only the actual files that are being used at run-time (like minified scripts) get included?
3. Will using *Bower* for "client-side" packages (like AngularJS 2, Bootstrap, jQuery, etc.) and using *npm* for node modules (like fs-extra) be a better option in as far as separation of concerns and ease of bundling later?
4. Could *WebPack* be used to produce only the needed files, at least for the "cient-side", so that only real node modules will be included with the app, while the rest of it will be in the form of web-pack compiled set of files?
5. Any practical tips on how this bundling of dependencies and distribution should be accredited out in practice? Gulp-scripts? Web-pack scripts? Project structure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am still in the learning curve of adopting the best practices in code deployment. But here is my starting list of what is recommended.

- Yes, `npm install --save-dev` is the first easiest thing to isolate dev and build specific packages. This includes gulp/grunt/webpack and its loaders or additional packages. These are used only for building and never in the code that actually is run. All packages used by the app should be installed with `npm install --save` so that it is project level available. So, in production, you would no npm install --production in machines which will not install dev packages at all. See  [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies?rq=1) for more info.
- While the original recommendation was to use bower for client side and npm for server side, both can be installed using npm too. After all, both does the same job of managing the packages and dependencies. However, if web pack is used, it is recommended that npm is used for client side dependencies also.
- package.json should be thought of managing the dependent packages only and not for building. For building and picking only the required files, you need task runners like gulp/grunt or bundlers like web pack.
- While gulp/grunt is very popular for build automation which includes bundling all dependent javascript in file and minifying them in to one file, webpack/browserify is a better option as it supports module import. Module import is intuitive way of require one module in another in node js type of coding 
  `var util = require('./myapp/lib/utils.js')` This is powerful way of mentioning the required dependencies in the code. The web pack builder runs like gulp as build process. But instead of looking through html file for all js files, looks at starting js file and and determines all dependent code mentioned by the require statements recursively and packages accordingly. It also minifies the code. It also loads css and image files in one bundle to reduce server trips. If needed, some modules can be configured to be loaded at runtime dynamically further reducing page load. [NPM vs. Bower vs. Browserify vs. Gulp vs. Grunt vs. Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062852/npm-vs-bower-vs-browserify-vs-gulp-vs-grunt-vs-webpack?rq=1) discusses this at length.
- Webpack can be used to bundle client side app optimally while server side need not be bundled or minified as there is no download.
- In web pack, though you can mention dependent modules with lib file path, the recommendation is to npm install all dependencies and mention the module name. For example if you have installed jquery, instead of giving path like /libs/jquery.min.js, you can mention as 'jquery'. Webpack will automatically pull the jquery lib and dependencies and minimise it. If they are common modules, it will be chunked too. So, it is better to npm install dependent packages instead of bower install.

  - ES2015 provides lot of benefits during coding time including type checking and modules. However all browsers do not yet support the spec natively. So you need to transpile the code to older version that browsers understand. This is done by transpilers like Babel that can be run with gulp. Webpack has in-built babel loader so web pack understands ES2015. It is recommended to use ES2015 module system as it will soon become the defacto way of coding and since there is transpiler, there is no worry of this not being supported in IE8/9.
  - For project structure you could have
- server
- client

  - src containing js files
  - dist containing html and build files generated

webpack.dev.config.js and webpack.prod.config.js can be at root level.

I have found that this area is an ocean and different schools of best practices.This is probably one set of best practices. Feel free to choose the set that works for your scenario. Look forward for more comments to add to this set.