# VS2017, ASP.net, Typescript, and npm

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, npm

I have an existing ASP.net application in Visual Studio. Until recently I only used JavaScript. Now I want use Typescript. Installing and transpiling works great. However, I got stuck when I wanted to import modules.

My idea was to use npm for loading modules, e.g. I added to `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "typestyle": "^1.7.1",
}
```

which I want to import in my .ts file via:

```
import { style } from 'typestyle';
```

The problem: npm downloads to folder `node_modules` which does not belong to my project (but it is inside my project folder); the import statement does not find the required files.

Currently I am using requirejs to enable import statements as explained [here](https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2014/05/27/Adding-RequireJS-to-an-ASPNET-MVC-project). My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

I can download `typestyle.js` manually, put it in my project folder, and configure the requirejs configuration file `main.js` so that it finds it. But then I am not using npm.

How can I import modules that I loaded with npm? I'd like to use requirejs. I do not want Angular or React. If possible I also want to avoid other things which make my project unnecessarily complicated (Mocha, node.js, knockout, Webpack, Gulp, Browserify, ...)

**EDIT**

Okay, after reading [NPM vs. Bower vs. Browserify vs. Gulp vs. Grunt vs. Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062852/npm-vs-bower-vs-browserify-vs-gulp-vs-grunt-vs-webpack?rq=1) I guess I do need a module bundler like Webpack or Browserify. But maybe there is some tool integrated in VS2017 which I could use?

**EDIT2**

And after reading [How it feels to learn JavaScript in 2016](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f) (note: this is 2018)  I understand that it might be too much to ask for a simple solution...

Comment: if you have already installed npm globally using  then check the version of npm installed using `npm -v` in command prompt . I think you have to provide the path to the node_modules folder in `visual studio -> Option` as given in this link below https://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2015FixingDependenciesNpmNotInstalledFromFseventsWithNodeOnWindows.aspx

Comment: I am using the in VS2017 integrated npm. It is version 3.3.4 and located in <VS-install-dir>/Web/External/npm.cmd. But even if I changed the node_modules path, how would requirejs know in which subfolder to look for any specific .js file?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution which suits my needs. Since it is very lengthy I'll just post the link ([project source code](https://github.com/UltimaBeaR/AspNetWebpackTutorial/tree/19cd8cade1df10e6bdc5cdeed949abec2c3e0673))
http://codingsight.com/using-npm-webpack-and-typescript-to-create-simple-aspnet-core-web-app/

Only drawback so far: It uses Webpack instead of requirejs. Webpack is a module packer. All .js files/modules are combined into one huge .js. No lazy loading by default.