# Polymer: Why do I need to use npm and bower?

Tags: spring-mvc, polymer, thymeleaf, cdn, web-component

I would like to develop a web application with Spring Boot, Spring Web MVC and Thymeleaf. I recently stumbled upon Web Components and Polymer which might be a good addition to Thymeleaf in order to use cool components. As I'm a frontend noob, I ask myself why I need this npm and bower stuff in order to use Polymer.

If I got it right, Web Components and Polymer are just js libraries. Why can't I just include them (maybe by using a cdn) in my html page? I like Thymeleaf as it's possible to view the pages without the need to have a webserver. If I could just include polymer as js library that would still work. I am quite sure that I misunderstand some major concepts, but I can't grab it. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: This question & answers can give you some insight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062852/npm-vs-bower-vs-browserify-vs-gulp-vs-grunt-vs-webpack/35064297#35064297.

Comment: So in the end it's manly because of the dependencies, right?

Comment: That's right, those are dependency managers. I personally use npm/yarn for every project that needs dependencies.