# How to update multiple bundled js files using webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack, websocket

I have a simple app in which require a user to provide certain pieces of information as follows.

1. Please provide your domain .

   **user: www.google.com**
2. Please provide your vast URL.

   **user: www.vast.xx.com**
3. Please select position.
   a) Bottom left.
   b) Bottom right.

   user: **b) Bottom right**

After the user provides these pieces of information the button `generate code` appears, the user clicks to generate code. He gets the following code.

```
 (function (w,d,s,o,f,js,fjs) {
            w['JS-Widget']=o;w[o] = w[o] || function () { (w[o].q = w[o].q || []).push(arguments) };
            js = d.createElement(s), fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            js.id = o; js.src = f; js.async = 1; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(window, document, 'script', 'mw', 'www.mywebisite.com/widget123.js'));
        mw('init', { someConfiguration: 448 });
        mw('message', 'x');
    </script>
```

Here is my full webpack config file: [webpack config](https://github.com/throne1986/embedable-javascript-widget-for-users/blob/master/webpack.config.js)
With this script, a user can use it on his website, the important thing here to note is `www.mywebisite.com/widget123.js` this is bundled js file generated by webpack as follow.

Here is part of my code I use to generate bundled js files using webpack by running a command `npm run build`

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// ...
return [{
  entry: './src/main.js',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ title: 'Caching' }),
  ],
  output: {
    **filename: 'widget.[contenthash].js',**
    path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
  }
}]
```

To generate the bundled js file each time a user generates a new code I need to run `npm run build` to do that I am using WebSockets to send a command to the server as follows.

```
HTML (client)

    <html>
    <body>
     <button onClick="sendCommands()"> Generate Code</button>
    </body>
    <script>

    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9898/');
   function sendCommands(){
    ws.onopen = function() {
        console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
        ws.send('npm run build');
    };
   } 
    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
    };

    </script>
    </html>
```

Here is Server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(9898);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

    connection.on('message', function(message) {
      console.log(message.utf8Data);
      const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(message.utf8Data);
      console.log('stdout:', stdout);
      console.log('stderr:', stderr);
      connection.sendUTF('Hi this is WebSocket server!');
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log('Client has disconnected.');
    });
});
```

**Problem :**

> Now let assume I have 4 users in which each of them have generated
>   their own js bundle file in dist folder I will have four files like
>   this: `widget4321.js, widget3345.js, widget1123.js, widget4321.js`

Assume I have changed the color of my widget, How do I update these files using webpack?.

**Note: please be free to provide another solution if you have one thanks.**

Comment: Don't use `contenthash` then. Use a hash of the user name, so everyone will have their own unique URL that will be stable over time without exposing the details.

Comment: If it is about styling isn't loading dynamically css with javascript an option, then when you update the css on your serve all clients will use the new css. If it is some features that you want to add to your widget(maybe you update the javascript) then you can have a small database to store reference between the user info and generated bundle file. Then when you want to update the files you recompile them and overwrite with the new content.

Comment: @pawel cam you provide some example on that?

Comment: @codtex now how do I do that? can you provide your solution in the code example? am newbie to webpack though, thanks

Comment: Maybe something like setting the hash from user data in env, e.g. `UID=df98ad npm run build` and then `filename: widget${process.env.UID}.js` in webpack config, or use `widget.js` as the file name and  `path: dist/${UID}/`. 
To rebuild the widgets after your codebase changes you'd also need to keep the original payload and re-use it, e.g. store them as `buildparams_${UID}.json`

Comment: I will be testing it, if it works I will get back to accept your answer if you put your solution as an answer, thanks

Comment: Hi Pawel thanks for your help, I tried that's in my webpack config script but  I was not able to solve my problems, can you please show your solution using my codes above? I will appreciate your help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `'widget.[contenthash].js'` content hash and it will change every time content of the file is changed so you can not associate a file with user

What you can do is instead of using `contenthash` you could do something like this

```
{
  output {
    filename: `widget.${someUserSpecificId}.js`
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

now the question is how you will get to pass the `someUserSpecificId` in configuration. To do that you can use Webpack's [environment-options](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#environment-options)

now in webpack configuration if you export a function instead of object like this

```
function (env, arg) {
  return {
    ...
    ...
    output: {
      filename: `widget.${env.someUserSpecificId}.js`
      ...
      ...
  }
}
```

and now you can pass the `env.someUserSpecificId` with cli option like

```
 webpack --env.someUserSpecificId=foo
```

now you can update any bundle for any user as you like

**NOTE** be aware that you don't use actual user id in filename because it will be exposed to client instead generate some random id for each user which is ok to expose on client and unique to each user

---

**UPDATE** method above described is good for updating some specific bundle but if you want to update all the bundle in one go you have to tweak the logic a bit

Instead of passing the `someUserSpecificId` from command line argument you can do this

```
const usersIdArray = ['userId1', 'userId2', ...otherUsersId];

const webpackConfig = userIdArray.map(someUserSpecificId => {
  return {
    ...
    ...
    output: {
      filename: `widget.${someUserSpecificId}.js`
      ...
      ...
    }
  };
});

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

what it will do is it will give you a array of multiple webpack config and you can pass that array directly to webpack and webpack will update all the files according to respective config [see exporting multiple configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations)

**Note** if you have very large array of users please batch your task in small segment

**Other Optimization idea** because you are running this task on your server it would be good to think of some optimization to reduce repetitive task one idea i have right now is you can build bundles in two part 1. will contain user specific config 2. will contain your code

so if user change his configuration you have to build only that part and if you change your configuration then also you have to build that only once because your common code will be same for all users ( like theme )

and when you creating final bundle just combine user-specific configuration with your code that way you can reduce repetitive task and it would be a lot faster

Comment: Hi by your solution Will I be able to update all bundled js files at once? Because I don't want to update these files standalone, as I said assume I have decided to change the background colour of my widget for all users,

Comment: Yes you can do that too but to update all the files you have to tweak the logic a bit. I will update that case in the answer as well

Comment: hi here is my config file I tried but not working  can you please check out : https://github.com/throne1986/embedable-javascript-widget-for-users/blob/master/webpackserver.js

Comment: @user9964622 there are couple of things wrong 1. don't need to return in arrow function when there is use of {} block  2. you are not exporting your `webpackConfig`

Comment: @user9964622 check my answer I have updated it  use `module.exports` and in `map` arrow function I have updated it to be more clear

Comment: Thanks for help bro, I changed as u suggested here is my webpack script update https://github.com/throne1986/embedable-javascript-widget-for-users/blob/master/webpackserver.js  but now when I run the script nothing happen and there is no errors, can you please check it what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user9964622 I have made a pull check https://github.com/throne1986/embedable-javascript-widget-for-users/pull/2

Comment: Thank you so much bro , so now how to insert those ids dynamically to array after being generated?

Comment: @user9964622 it's simple javascript file you can use anything like you can read from a json file using `const userJson = fs.readFileSync(pathToJsonFile)` then `const user = JSON.parse(userJson)`

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier for you to have a single widget file (generated by you with the default configuration) and use the user-provided information as parameters.

domainName: www.google.com
vastUrl: www.vast.xx.com
position: Bottom right

```
 (function (w,d,s,o,f,js,fjs) {
            w['JS-Widget']=o;w[o] = w[o] || function () { (w[o].q = w[o].q || []).push(arguments) };
            js = d.createElement(s), fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            js.id = o; js.src = f; js.async = 1; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(window, document, 'script', 'mw', 'www.mywebisite.com/widget123.js'));
        mw('init', { 
                       someConfiguration: 448, 
                       domainName: 'www.google.com', 
                       vastUrl: 'www.vast.xx.com', 
                       position: 'bottom right'
                    });
        mw('message', 'x');
    </script>
```

Afterward, use the variables in your widget.

Then, updating the color of the widget will affect all the installed widgets and will keep the user's configuration.

Comment: Hi, That could be the easiest way to go, but in a JavaScript code we need to provide only bundled js file without the user Informations provided,  the solution provided above is not acceptable, note user Informations should be hidden