# How to generate unique file name using webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have webpack config configuration , I would like to generate a unique file name eg name123fr every time I run nmp run build, here is part of my code

```
return [{
        entry: './src/main.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'widget.js',
            path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
        }
}]
```

This generates me the following file: http://localhost:8080/widget.js

But I want something like this http://localhost:8080/widget23we23.js

the name should be unique each time I run `npm run build'

is this possible using webpack?

Comment: Will this do what you want? From the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/): "The `[contenthash]` substitution will add a unique hash based on the content of an asset. When the asset's content changes, `[contenthash]` will change as well."

Comment: let me check out , thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The webpack [documentation on caching](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) recommends using the `[contenthash]` substitution:

> The [contenthash] substitution will add a unique hash based on the content of an asset. When the asset's content changes, [contenthash] will change as well.

here's an example of what that would look like in your code snippet from above:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// ...
return [{
  entry: './src/main.js',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ title: 'Caching' }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'widget.[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
  }
}]
```

The output should then be something like this:

```
widget.7e2c49a622975ebd9b7e.js
```

This won't do exactly what you ask, because the name won't change with every single reload. But it will cause the file name to change when the code changes, and I suspect this is your desired outcome.

Comment: ur solution just give widget.[contenthash].js do I need to import something?

Comment: Sorry, yeah I forgot to add the plugins section. Answer is updated, hopefully it will work now!

Comment: Here is my repo : https://github.com/throne1986/widget check it out still the same , I have installed all plugin but nah working

Comment: Do any of these substitutions in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename) work for you? Like `[name]` or `[id]` or `[hash]`?

Comment: i found the problem is about webpack version hash works only on version abover 4.3 , now it works perfcetly , thanks for help if you dont mind check my another thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030506/how-to-create-a-unique-id-and-unique-js-bundle-for-each-generated-code

Comment: is it possible to generate bundlejs with webpack on browser? meaning the same as above but in browser

Comment: I've never seen anything like that. What would be the use case? I mean if you were waiting to bundle the js until it hits the browser, why bundle at all? I could see transpiling in the browser (babel can do that), if that's what you're getting at. I know a lot of times that transpile step is integrated with webpack.

Comment: I want to create widget which contains different configurations based on user Informations and domain, user provide pieces of information eg domain, position etc after that I want to bundle those configurations into one jsfile , so that I can create code for installation the widget on user website , hope u get what I want.

Comment: I have found some answers on stack over flow, some one wrote this below: "I found the answer of my own question. By using sockets we can send the command from client to server as a string, and on server using child process we can run that command received in a string via socket."

Comment: Ah, so you want to bundle on the server, but you want to be able to initiate the process from a request by the browser? Yeah, you could do that. You could use WebSockets, regular HTTP, etc. However I'd be very cautious about running a "command received in a string via socket"...that's really bad security practice. Other considerations: [command injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Command_Injection), [Denial of Service attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack), etc.